# How to add colored header to a panel CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a panel for my website. as follows.
CSS

```
 body {
         background-color: #f45b69;
         font-family: "Asap", sans-serif;
    }
     .login {
         overflow: hidden;
         background-color: blue;
         padding: 40px 30px 30px 30px;
         border-radius: 10px;
         position: absolute;
         top: 50%;
         left: 50%;
         width: 400px;
         -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
         box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(2, 128, 144, 0.2);
    }
     .login::before, .login::after {
         content: '';
         position: absolute;
         width: 600px;
         height: 600px;
         border-top-left-radius: 40%;
         border-top-right-radius: 45%;
         border-bottom-left-radius: 35%;
         border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
         z-index: -1;
    }
     .login::before {
         left: 40%;
         bottom: -130%;
         background-color: rgba(69, 105, 144, 0.15);
    
    }
     .login::after {
         left: 35%;
         bottom: -125%;
         background-color: rgba(2, 128, 144, 0.2);
    
    }
     .login > input {
         font-family: "Asap", sans-serif;
         display: block;
         border-radius: 5px;
         font-size: 16px;
         background: white;
         width: 100%;
         border: 0;
         padding: 10px 10px;
         margin: 15px -10px;
    }
     .login > button {
         font-family: "Asap", sans-serif;
         cursor: pointer;
         color: #fff;
         font-size: 16px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         width: 80px;
         border: 0;
         padding: 10px 0;
         margin-top: 10px;
         margin-left: -5px;
         border-radius: 5px;
         background-color: #f45b69;
    
    }
     .login > button:hover {
         background-color: #f24353;
    
    
    }
     a {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
         position: absolute;
         right: 10px;
         bottom: 10px;
         font-size: 12px;
    }
.login_header {
        background: url('https://jssors8.azureedge.net/demos/image-slider/img/faded-monaco-scenery-evening-dark-picjumbo-com-image.jpg') no-repeat center top / 100% auto;
background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;

}
```

```html
    <form class="login">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
      <button>Login</button>
    </form>
```

I want to add a colored curve header to it as the given image.

https://ibb.co/86VRKZJ

https://ibb.co/hc9H6R1

Additionally, the text "enter data" on it.  CSS or image header is accepted. but I want to add my own image locally if you use an image as a header. I am a newer and your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a demo of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two new elements have been added to the HTML code. `box` and `wrap`.
Two new classes for these elements have been added to the CSS.

The third new element `title` is for the title on the page

I hope I've been helpful

```css
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Asap", sans-serif;
}

.login {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 90px 30px 30px 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 55px);
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(2, 128, 144, 0.2);
}

.login::before,
.login::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border-top-left-radius: 40%;
    border-top-right-radius: 45%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 35%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.login::before {
    left: 40%;
    bottom: -130%;
    background: linear-gradient(2deg, rgba(69, 105, 144, 0.2) 0%, rgba(69, 105, 144, 0.2) 90%, rgba(69, 105, 144, 0) 96%);
}

.login::after {
    left: 35%;
    bottom: -125%;
    background: linear-gradient(2deg, rgba(2, 128, 144, 0.2) 0%, rgba(2, 128, 144, 0.2) 90%, rgba(69, 105, 144, 0) 96%);
}

.login>input {
    font-family: "Asap", sans-serif;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin: 15px -10px;
}

.login>button {
    font-family: "Asap", sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 80px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f45b69;

}

.login>button:hover {
    background-color: #f24353;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: -300px;
    right: -300px;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    height: 300px;
}

.box {
    background: url('https://jssors8.azureedge.net/demos/image-slider/img/faded-monaco-scenery-evening-dark-picjumbo-com-image.jpg') no-repeat center top / 100% auto;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 95px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -2;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form class="login">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
        <div class="wrap">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi,54ka. Thanks for your valuable time and coding. It is highly appreciated. but I expect this curve heading on panel. not on background page. please be kind to rearrange it for me. additionally need "some text" on header. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: thank you so much. but I expect this heading on panel . I mean as a form header. not a background page header. take a look here https://ibb.co/86VRKZJ( given in my question)

Comment: dear, sorry for bothering you. but version 1 is good. please bring that curved image header to the top of my login form. i mean please bring it on the top of username input box.

Comment: please take a look here. header must be inserted here   https://ibb.co/hc9H6R1

Comment: dear sir, there is a difference between your output and what i expect. i expect like this one https://ibb.co/hc9H6R1         i simply say please insert your image header to the place where the text "LOGIN FORM" has put.

Comment: i changed the login header like this                .login_header {
        background: url('https://jssors8.azureedge.net/demos/image-slider/img/faded-monaco-scenery-evening-dark-picjumbo-com-image.jpg') no-repeat center top / 100% auto;
background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;

}      now it is good and what i expected. please add a bottom curve.

Comment: I changed the login header. Try again

Comment: oh my god!. it is what i expect !. thanks  a lot dear. additionally need some centered text on image header. then header upper corners must be border radius 5px.

Comment: Great! :) You can mark this answer as accepted answer.

Comment: dear, a little mistake. there is a line on the bottom edge of image . can you remove it? other everything is fine

Comment: Hello, there is a line on the bottom edge of image . can you remove it? other everything is fine

Comment: Anyway I highly appreciate your valuable and wonderful coding. Thanks a million! also marked your answer as accepted.